# Filter ComboBox data-source in Apache Zeppelin

Tags: sql, apache-zeppelin

I have an [Apache Zepellin](https://zeppelin.apache.org/) project.

In my project I have two ComboBoxes set up as follows:

- `DropDownA`'s data-source is **1, 2, 3, 4, 5**.
- `DropDownB`'s data-source is **A, B, C, D, E**.

I need to filter a `DropDownB`'s data-source when `DropDownA`'s selected-value changes.

**Example**

Their rules are as follows:

1. Selecting **1** from `DropDownA` needs to trigger the data-source of `DropDownB` to filter to **C, D, E**.
2. Selecting **2** from `DropDownA` needs to trigger the data-source of `DropDownB` to filter to **A, C, E**.
3. Selecting **3** from `DropDownA` needs to trigger the data-source of `DropDownB` to filter to **E**.
4. Selecting **4** from `DropDownA` needs to trigger the data-source of `DropDownB` to filter to **C, D**.
5. Selecting **5** from `DropDownA` needs to trigger the data-source of `DropDownB` to filter to **D, E**.

Is there anyone with [Apache Zepellin](https://zeppelin.apache.org/) experience willing to help me?

Comment: A warm welcome to StackOverflow. I have done my best to improve the readability of your post while taking special care to preserve the original content. Please supply example code and data to help us resolve your issue.